# Why is Hilbert’s 11th problem still partially resolved?

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Hilbert’s 11th problem which demands that we  ‘classify quadratic forms over algebraic number fields’ has been of interest to me and I would like to know what makes it partially resolved currently. Or in other words, what does the progress made in recent times lack?
What equation(s) does one have to solve in particular to provide full solutions to the problem?

Comment: It would be helpful to remind the rest of us what is Hilbert's 11th problem. Those who aren't actively studying a particular Hilbert problem have trouble remembering which is which.

Comment: @DanFox I have edited the question. I hope I have made clear enough. Thanks

Comment: I think this is a good question. The article I posted as a comment to the OP's other question (https://jtnb.centre-mersenne.org/article/JTNB_2003__15_1_33_0.pdf) says that the work it discusses "essentially resolves the remaining open case of Hilbert's 11th problem." So exactly what is left is unclear to me, even though on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_problems it is indeed listed as only "partially resolved."

Comment: @SamHopkins  I recommend a contemporary survey by Schulze-Pillot  https://www.math.uni-sb.de/ag/schulze/Preprints/talca_survey.pdf    see also https://arxiv.org/search/?searchtype=author&query=Schulze-Pillot%2C+R

Comment: isn’t the issue that the bounds one gets are ineffective (Siegel zeroes)? in my nonexpert understanding you get a main term for the number of rep.s of $N$ which is something like the value of a Dirichlet $L$-function at 1 (maybe assoc. to the quad. char. with disc. the discriminant of your form, maybe I’m implicitly imagining it’s diag.) times the usual local const.s (which at infinity gives the expected $N^{1/2}$) plus an error term which you effectively upper bound via a subconvex estimate (which saves a small power), and so you need $L(1,\chi)$ to not be too small, whence Siegel zeroes.

Comment: (sorry to be clear I’m only talking about ternary forms and squarefree $N$ above (so that one avoids the usual issue that ternary forms miss square classes etc.), for quaternary forms and up the situation is much better!)

Comment: Thanks @alpoge for your feedback. I recently learned of this problem from Wikipedia but I am not very familiar with some of the terms you spoke of. However I can currently solve equations as would appear below:ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 = d and ax^2 + bxy + cy^2 + dyz + ez^2 + fz = g for real number and integer solutions depending on how the question is framed. But I don’t if that’s just enough to Hilbert’s 11th problem or not

Comment: @JamalAgbanwa: It would be easier for all of us if you told us how much mathematics you know. For instance, do you understand the terms used in Cogdell's article that Sam Hopkins gave you above? Or is your mathematical knowledge closer to high-school level? Knowing this would help people know how to formulate their answers so that you be able to understand them.

Comment: @AlexM. my actual mathematical knowledge is high school level but I however read wide when I have the chance.I don’t really understand the article given to me but it’s something I would have used as a reference for the introduction in my paper I wanted to write. The equations in my reply to Alpoge are what I can solve but I don’t know if that’s enough to solve the problem. If not, I wanted to know which other equations(or quadratic forms) whose solutions would literally solve Hilbert’s 11th completely.